# Is there a way to "fill" a cell so that the fill color is visible with the text as it overflows on to adjacent cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Note: Filling adjacent cells separately is not practical as expanding and contracting columns in other areas of the sheet cause the text to be out of the range of the filled cells.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far and exactly what you expect to accomplish. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't adjust the cell width to match the data inside? Double click the right border of the cell header (the line between ` A | B | C ` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a supported behavior in Excel, but there are 1-2 (I'd say janky) workarounds. See this [mrexcel thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/52377-background-color-behind-text-not-entire-cell.html), but I don't believe this is something that will morph to match your data and must be done on a cell-by-cell basis. I'm sure there is some VBA solution but it sounds like you would be better off assessing how your data could best be displayed.